# How to loop on each element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, roblox

I am trying to make selenium click each avatar and put it on a tab for each, but my code isn't working.

```
driver.get("https://www.roblox.com/groups/650266/Trade#!/about")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('group-dropdown').click()
driver.find_element_by_id("role-3874587").click()
for i in range(0, 9, 10):
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("avatar-container").click()
```

Error Message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Picture

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qAHa.png
```

Comment: Just a question why do u use the 
```
getAvatorElements.get(i).click();
```
what does the get(i) do?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with python very much. But, I know Selenium and my code are in Java. So, logic should be same. You need find WebElements using by this cssSelector

```
    div[class='section'] > div:nth-child(4) > ul > li
```

And, then put it into these WebElements into the List.Then, You need to iterate by using for loot to click each element. Hope this help!

Edit: This is java code.

```
    List<WebElement> getAvatorElements = 
    driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[class='section'] > div:nth- 
    child(4) > ul > li"));
    for(int i=0; i< getAvatorElements.size();i++)
    {
        getAvatorElements.get(i).click();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the for loop you are using .
in the loop you are iterating from 0 to 9 with an increment of 10 it should be 1 or don't write anything just start and end will work.

`for i in range(0, 9, 1):`

or this

```
for i in range(0, 9):
```

Comment: It worked but I want it to loop through all the people in that current bracket in the group they are listed in for example I want to find the people that are Rich Traders I want it to go through all the people. That's what I am trying to do.